# Most feasible way to display images in android and ios app

Tags: android, ios

i want to display around 1000+ images into an application. Which is the most effective way to store images, on device or in database ?

I am using sqlite database in my app.

Comment: is there any relationships in/between on how the image object are displayed?

Comment: Try encoding the images using base64 encoding  or others , then store the encoded value in db and decode them when you want to display them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your image on server than download it in device, save your image into sdcard as a cache or simple image. At download on single success of image store its path into your table and used in your application.

Use Lazy loading concept to load image in application. Its better to store image in sdcard rather than in database.

Answer (score 0):

In android or ios dont save large images into database In sqlite or in core data it can lead to database inconsistency and the database like sqlite are not designed for saving large  images.

In android use
[Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)  or [External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

In ios use
[iOS File System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you store the image in server. But if you dont have access to a server, then store the image path in SQLite database and have the images in sdcard. It is always a good programming practice to do like this.